# Java game framework drawImage error

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

So, for my first Java class I was asked to use inheritance and polymorphism to make a game. Everything does what it's supposed to, except for the the 2nd (and last) game object I added to the game. Each object's attributes are stored in "GameObject" class (position, direction, storing the image of each game object (player)). There are two game objects, "Player" and "Virus", each extending "GameObject". The problem is, when I call the "draw" method for the Virus, it starts to mimic the movement of the Player object, which is moving correctly. For now, I don't want the Virus image to move at all, but it still does. Any help???

```
public Virus()
{
super("virus.png", 500.0, 300.0);
}

public void update()
{
    // This outputs 500 + "\n" + 300 the ENTIRE time, even when both images move!!! 
    System.out.println(this.xPos() + "\n" + this.yPos());
    this.updateCollisionRect();
}

public void draw (Graphics g)
  {
  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g; // Set up 2D graphics from draw's parameter Graphics.
  g2d.drawImage(this.getBufferedImage(), (int)this.xPos(), (int)this.yPos(), null);
  g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
  g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(this.getDegree()), this.xPos() + this.getBufferedImage().getWidth() / 2.0,
                                               this.yPos() + this.getBufferedImage().getHeight() / 2.0);
  g2d.draw(getCollisionRect());
  }
}
```

https://app.box.com/s/fse2uzropusbz400siwf

Comment: Do you have a link to the full code?  Also, the snippet you included does not show the inheritance that you mentioned.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/flawedjavaframeworkgame1/files/latest/download?source=navbar

Comment: Your rotating the Graphics context without resetting, this will effect everything painted after it. Try using (Graphics2D)g.create(); on the first line and add g2d.dispose() as the last statement. This will allow you to create a copy of the Graphics object, whose changes won't effect others using the master context

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer!!! I can't believe it was this easy. I instead used "Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();" as my first line, but all the same! Now it finally does what it's suppose to. It's just weird that it detects collisions from the image and not the collisionRectangle. I guess more testing and drinking, lol. Thank you all!